# Mysql server has gone away. Error while reading greeting packet

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp, wampserver

While connecting to MySql, I am getting an error `MySql server has gone away`

on this line `$db = mysqli_connect("localhost:9080","root","XXXX");`

Here is my code.

```
<?php
  ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
  ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);

  define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:9080');
  define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'api');

   //$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
   $db = mysqli_connect("localhost:9080","root","");

  // Check connection
  if (!$db) 
  {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$select_db)
  {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($db));
  }

  echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

I've tried to add

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

And updated `max_allowed_Packet` to 16 M.

Then Restart all Services.

Error Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LndYS.jpg

Comment: `$connection` is undefined in your code!!

Comment: Is your MySQL Server actually listening on port 9080? And if so Why?

Comment: Also look at parameter **4** of a `mysqli_connect()` and then you can loose the `mysqli_db_select()`

Comment: @Saty I agree but the error is in this line $db = mysqli_connect("localhost:9080","root","");

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes It's listening to port 9080

Comment: @Mayank Bhuvnesh  you need 4 parameter in `$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");`

Comment: @PavanBaddi I have tried that also but no luck. Attached the error screenshot plz check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection to the database saved the connection handle/object in a variable called `$db` but your attempt to select a database to use attempts to use a variable called `$connection` So its just a copy/paste TYPO really.

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:9080');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'api');

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);

// Check connection
if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_DATABASE);
//               the error      ^^^^^^^^^^^
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($db, DB_DATABASE);
if(!$select_db) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($db));
}

echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

**Small Note**

You can accomplish a connection and a database selections all in the `mysql_connect()` function using the 4th parameter like this.

The `mysqli_db_select()` function in MySQL is really there for when you want to select a different database at some point in the normal flow of your script, and not for use when initially connection to a database.

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:9080');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'api');

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

**From comments below.....**

By default `MySQL` runs on port 3306, `MariaDB` runs on 3307 in WAMPServer.

So change

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:9080');
```

To either

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3306');  // default MYSQL
```

or

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3307');  // default MariaDB
```

> You can also now remove the
>
> ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
>
> ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
>
> and revert the `max_allowed_Packet` back to its default

Comment: I completely agree  but the error is in line $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);

Also I have attached the Error screenshot. Plz check.

I have also updated $connection to $db but error is same.

Comment: I cannot actually read the image, its too small, but I do know WAMPServer. When you decided to move MySQL from port 3306 to 9080, how did you do it? And which version of WAMPServer are you using

Comment: I have updated the port in httpd.conf file. I am using WAMP Server 5.7.14

Comment: There is no WAMPServer 5.7.14, there is a MySQL 5.7.14 though

Comment: Also the `httpd.conf` file does not effect or control the port number that MySQL Server listens on. Do you mean you have changed the port that Apache is Listening on from 80 to 9080 **NOTE** Apache and MySQL are not the same thing and do not listen on the same port, obviously.

Comment: Yup MySql Version is 3.0.6 64bit and port is 3307

Comment: I would suggest that you upgrade WAMPServer to 3.0.9 [available here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) that will only change WAMPServer internal code, and not your MYSQL/PHP/Apache

Comment: ___and port is 3307___ then use `define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3307');` Although the normal port is ___3306___ **UNLESS** you are actually using `MariaDB` when  the default port is ___3307___

Comment: Thanx buddy. Port was the real issue. Thnx a lot.

Comment: I added to my answer all this stuff about port numbers